# Bonding wifi and ethernet because of dodgy ethernet connection

Tags: linux, home-networking, powerline-networking, bonding

I do not have a direct line to my router from my server, so I've got a powerline adapter in the room which should give it a wired connection. Now lately I'm getting problems with it, it can barely ping the router or with a lot of latency.

It does also have a wireless connection so now I'm messing around with bonding (I want to acces it with 1 static ip not 2 seperate ip's for wired and wireless). Active backup mode was looking real promising at first but since the wired connection doesnt go down when im getting 1000ms ping to my router it's off the table. At the moment I am using the broadcasting mode which seems to be working (for now) but this seems like it's very ineffecient.

Any ideas how I should go about optimizing my setup?

Sorry if this is a bit of ramble.

Comment: You should investigate what is corrupting the powerline signal (just unplug/turn-off  everything until the ping time becomes good). Very often you'll find it's some switching power supply (phone charger, but it could also be the server's own power supply, in which case try to use separate wall sockets).

Comment: Not a clue what is corrupting the line, even when the powerline has its own socket I,m still getting bad ping times.